# Intel Vtune: Power driver not accessible

Tags: intel, intel-vtune

I'm trying to run Intel vtune power analysis on intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU running Ubuntu 13.04 i keep getting "Power driver is inaccessible. Make sure the driver is installed and you have permission to access it." I tried building and loading drivers manually, the sepdk builds and loads correctly but loading the powerdk driver gives the error

"Setting group ownership of device to group "vtune" ... ./insmod-apwr: 475: [: vtune: unexpected operator
Not managed to install the driver with the proper group. Wrong group is  vtune
Setting group ownership of device to group "vtune" ... ./insmod-apwr: 475: [: vtune: unexpected operator
Not managed to install the driver with the proper group. Wrong group is  vtune
Setting group ownership of device to group "vtune" ... ./insmod-apwr: 475: [: vtune: unexpected operator
Not managed to install the driver with the proper group. Wrong group is  vtune
./insmod-apwr: 487: [: vtune: unexpected operator
Setting file permissions on device to "660" ... done.
./insmod-apwr: 514: [: vtune: unexpected operator
./insmod-apwr: 528: [: unexpected operator
The apwr3_1 driver has been successfully loaded."

Could it be that my processor is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

The articles below lists suggestions for troubleshooting most common problems with the power analysis feature.For example please make sure that you load the driver specifying existing group you are member of (case 3)

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/troubleshooting-vtunetm-amplifier-xes-power-analysis